# Pass SelectedRows from LWC Datatable to Apex

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, data-types

I'm still very new to Salesforce/Apex development but I'm struggling to understand how I would pass the SelectedRows of a datatable through to Apex. I've managed to pass simple data types through on the click of a button but I'm not sure as to what the datatype of the list/array would need to be within Apex. Ideally I would still need to access not only the Id of the SelectedRow but also the data contained within the row. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

LWC JS

```javascript
handleConfirm(){
    createNewRec({stringNameType: this.stringNameType, lstSelectedRecords})
    .then(result =>{
        this.result = result;
    })
    .catch(error =>{
        this.error = error;
    })
}
```

Apex

```apex
@AuraEnabled
public static String createNewRec(String stringNameType, List<???>lstSelectedRecords){
    String returnResult = 'something';
    system.debug('stringNameType: ' + stringNameType + ' lstSelectedRecords ' +lstSelectedRecords);
    return returnResult;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per documentation:

`selectedRows` - The data in the rows that are selected.

#### Standard/Custom Objects

If your datatable displays some kind of Standard or Custom object.
You can pass `List<YourStandardObject>` or `List<YourCustomObject>`

```java
@AuraEnabled
public static void createNewRecord(List<Account> selectedRecords) {
    insert selectedRecords;
}
```

#### Others

You can always pass `List<Map<String, Object>>` and do some mapping in Apex.

```java
@AuraEnabled
public static void createNewRecord(List<Map<String, Object>> selectedRecords) {
    // mapping here
    // example
    List<Account> accountsToInsert = new List<Account>();
    for (Map<String, Object> fields : selectedRecords) {
         accountsToInsert.add(
            new Account(
               Name = fields.get('Name')
            )
         );
     }
    insert accountsToInsert;
}
```